# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu too big

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I cannot figure out why my bootstrap dropdown menu seems to have an extra line on top and line on the bottom--with nothing in them. Granted, I have made my navbar 150px for all resolutions but that doesn't explain the extra padding on the bottom. This is my first bootstrap project and I have searched high and low for an answer to this. You have to narrow the window to less than 767 pixels for the dropdown option to appear.

This is the page: http://www.ashlandlockandsafe.com/index3.html.

In the CSS, I have tried to address it with the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-header{
    height:150px;
}

.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.well {
    font-size:2.5em;
    text-align:center;
    text:#000;
    padding:0;
    border:#000 solid 4px;
    background-image:url(../images/metal.png);
    background-image:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;

 }
.carhelp {
    margin-top:15px;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
    }

.phonetxt {
    font-size:36px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

But it still has what appears to be an extra row on the top and bottom. Any ideas how to address the dropdown itself?

Comment: Maybe I'am blind but I don't see any dropdown on that page? Can you explain further?

Comment: Narrow the window to look like mobile size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In website, fixed header has a padding `.navbar-fixed-top .nav{60px 0px}` causing the problem.

so solution is media queries

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top .nav {
        padding: 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

so on devices like mobile, it will over-ride the default `.navbar-fixed-top .nav` selector property.

More information about [media-queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Comment: Thanks so much! You have made my day! Works like a charm now.